# Sublime Text - Is there a way to automatically split tags onto new line?

Tags: html, sublimetext2

I used a table generator to to convert a large Excel file into HTML, but much of the code runs across the same line, as shown below:

```
<tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>25%</td><td>25%</td><td>40%</td><td>10%</td></tr>
 <tr><td>IV</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;    </td></tr>
```

Is there a way for Sublime text to automatically break the tags onto individual lines for ease in adding all of the class styling I need to add?

Looking for the following:

```
 <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>5%</td>
    <td>0%</td>
    <td>95%</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
    <td>II</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
 </tr>
```

Comment: XML pretty print? https://github.com/alek-sys/sublimetext_indentxml

Answer (score 4):

The idea is first insert new line character after each tag, then re-indenting of code.

First Find all `>` characters, then replace it with `>\n` (Regular expression), then go to `Edit`, `Line`->`Reindent`. This way you can indent your code!

Answer (score 1):

If you have the [Tag](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Tag) package installed you can simply select from the menu:

```
Edit -> Tag -> Auto-format Tags on Document
```

Answer (score 0):

if you have text within tags, indentation on siblings tag can happen on differen columns.
After the first search/replace you can should another to put on a new line closing tags after text:
search: (\w+)<
replace $1\n<

And then Edit, Line->Reindent

Answer (score 0):

**Easy steps and no packages are required!**

- press <kbd>crtl</kbd>+<kbd>h</kbd> to open replace popup
- replace all `><` with

  ```
  >
  <
  ```
- <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> to select all, then <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd> and select `reindent lines`

That was it it's done!

---

**Simplly replace**

> ><

**with **

> > 
> <

and you are good to go!